# regex match whole word and punctuation with it using re.search()

Tags: python, regex, qregularexpression

New to regex.
Aim- To match a whole word which might have either '.' or '-' with it at the end. I want to keep it for the .start() and .end() position calculation.

```
txt = "The indian in. Spain."
pattern = "in."

x = re.search(r"\b" + pattern + r"\b" , txt)

print(x.start(), x.end())
```

I want the position for 'in.' word, as highlighted "The indian **in.** Spain.". The expression I have used gives error for a Nonetype object.
What would be the expression to match the '.' in the above code? Same if '-' is present instead of '.'

Comment: you should escape the ".", "\."

Comment: I tried writing `pattern = "in\." ` but it did not work.

Comment: x = re.search(r"(in\.)", txt)

Comment: It worked! But is there a way this matches only the whole word. On using this for txt = "plain. The indian in. Spain" it showed the position for "in." in "plain."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. In regex `.` is special. It means "match one of any character". However, you are trying to use it to match a regular period. (It will indeed match that, but it will also match everything else.) Instead, to match a period, you need to use the pattern `\.`. And to change that to match either a period or a hyphen, you can use a class, like `[-.]`.
2. You are using `\b` at the end of your pattern to match the word boundary, but `\b` is [defined as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) being the boundary between a word character and a non-word character, and periods and spaces are both non-word characters. This means that Python won't find a match. Instead, you could use a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), which will match whatever character you want, but won't consume the string.

Now, to match a whole word - any word - you can do something like `\w+`, which matches one or more word characters.

Also, it is quite possible that there won't be a match anyway, so you should check whether a match occurred using an `if` statement or a `try` statement. Putting it all together:

```
txt = "The indian in. Spain."
pattern = r"\w+[-.]"
x = re.search(r"\b" + pattern + r"(?=\W)", txt)
if x:
    print(x.start(), x.end())
```

## Edit

There is one problem with the lookahead assertion above - it won't match the end of the string. This means that if your text is `The rain in Spain.` then it won't match `Spain.`, as there is no non-word character following the final period.

To fix this, you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), which matches when the following text does *not* include the pattern, and also does not consume the string.

```
x = re.search(r"\b" + pattern + r"(?!\w)", txt)
```

This will match when the character after the word is anything other than a word character, including the end of the string.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!